# Sort between two dates in excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an excel database with several dates. My dates are in range D, and I want to fine the start date and end date from my range. Please help!

I using this code:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Name").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
Criteria1:=txtSDate.Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=txtEDate.Value
```

And I also have two buttons using the code below:

```
Private Sub txtEDate_Change()
If txtEDate.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Date! "
    Exit Sub
End If
If txtEDate.TextLength = 2 Or txtEDate.TextLength = 5 Then
    txtEDate.Text = txtEDate.Text + "."
End If
If txtEDate.TextLength = 2 Or txtEDate.TextLength = 5 Then
txtEDate.Text = txtEDate.Text + "DD/MM/YYYY"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtSDate_Change()
If txtSDate.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Date! "
    Exit Sub
End If
If txtSDate.TextLength = 2 Or txtSDate.TextLength = 5 Then
    txtSDate.Text = txtSDate.Text + "."
End If
If txtSDate.TextLength = 2 Or txtSDate.TextLength = 5 Then
txtSDate.Text = txtSDate.Text + "DD/MM/YYYY"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please [provide additional details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the start and end date use simply

```
Sub test()
Dim Mindt As Date
Dim Maxdt As Date

Mindt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("A1:A10")) 'change range as needed
Maxdt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A1:A10")) 'change range as needed

End Sub
```

Your cells in range must be formated as date